# Градиент на CSS3

Tags: css3, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такой [градиент](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6uA3.png) на CSS3, без картинок. С помощью каких сервисов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #f5f8f9;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f5f8f9 0%, #1d97d3 50%, #0591d5 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #f5f8f9), color-stop(50%, #1d97d3), color-stop(100%, #0591d5));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f5f8f9 0%, #1d97d3 50%, #0591d5 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f5f8f9 0%, #1d97d3 50%, #0591d5 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f5f8f9 0%, #1d97d3 50%, #0591d5 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f5f8f9 0%, #1d97d3 50%, #0591d5 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f8f9', endColorstr='#0591d5', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bv5hmrz/

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
вот есть такой сервис

Comment: Тоже хотел этот сервис посоветовать.) Всегда им пользуюсь.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю сервис, всегда в закладке есть открытое окно с ним, заодно он помог мне понять, как разрулить проблемы c градиентом в разных версиях IE.

Answer (score 4):

Да ну нет же! Не с помощью сервисов, а с помощью background-image:

```
#gradient {
.horizontal(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(@start-color @start-percent), color-stop(@end-color @end-percent)); // Safari 5.1-6, Chrome 10+
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent); // Standard, IE10, Firefox 16+, Opera 12.10+, Safari 7+, Chrome 26+
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=1)",argb(@start-color),argb(@end-color))); // IE9 and down
}
}
```

извините за less, упрощаю себе жизнь немного :)

Comment: Даже несмотря на LESS, который ещё компилить надо, ваш вариант не будет работать в IE9 без отключения фильтра, а repeat-x совсем не нужно, у вас же в настройках написано, что градиент будет занимать 100% background.

Comment: да как бы вам сказать... Less, вне всякого сомнения, компилить надо. Но не предлагаете же вы писать все стили вручную?
А в IE9 этот вариант работает.

Comment: @MasterAlex Зря вы придираетесь к LESS. Если вы нормальный разработчик, вы будете пользоваться препроцессорами.   
P.S. Я не сказал, что тот, кто ими не пользуется, - ненормальный разработчик. ))

Comment: @Nasty Pacman, @inferusvv, препроцессоры это очень удобный и полезный иструмент, ускоряющий скорость вёрстки, в теории... а на практике, к примеру, у вас стартап, где дизайнер феерит идеями по улучшению сайта каждую неделю, ещё и новые дизайны делает 1-2 раза в год, а если 2 дизайнера, которые делают сайт по страницам, половину 1 дизайнер, половину другой, ситуации бывают разные, поэтому я считаю, что в 70% проектов внедрение LESS не ускоряет разработку, а замедляет, это даже если не учитывать время на интеграцию его в проект.

Comment: @MasterAlex что ж это за проект такой, где нет общего выдержанного стиля? И даже если так, как вас LESS в этом помешает? Ну никак же. Наоборот проще.

Comment: @MasterAlex, вам нужно учиться. Интеграция less (или sass — это уж дело вкуса) в проект сводится к паре простых записей в gruntfile. grunt-contrib-watch позволяет не вспоминать о компиляции, компилит всё сам при изменениях исходников.

А бардак в проекте — это уж не вина препроцессоров. Старайтесь просто избегать таких проектов, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @inferusvv, @Елена Левина, я не против препроцессоров, но опять же повторюсь - в теории всё идеально, а когда дело доходит до практики, зачастую эффективнее писать чистый css, чем пытаться структурировать проект под препроцессор (лично мой опыт, и да, я разбирал исходники twitter bootstrap и верстал одну подработку с использованием less). А по поводу бардака, то на проектах обычно не пишут - "дизайнер мегакреативен :)", пока не поработаешь, не узнаешь.

Comment: В теории, может, и идеально, а на практике просто хорошо. А уж структурировать проект нужно независимо от того, используете ли вы препроцессоры. И не берите плохие макеты в работу. От этого же вся индустрия страдает. Масса плохих сайтов из-за этого. Дизайнеров надо воспитывать, обучать. Большинство из них умеет играться шрифтами, но совершенно не представляет, как работает браузер, и даже сколько эти их шрифты весят. Эти же дизайнеры потом удивляются, почему какой-нибудь лайфхакер открывается на мобильном две минуты, при этом сначала показываются картинки, а потом только проявляются шрифты.

Comment: @Елена Левина, структурирование проекта и структурирование под препроцессор это разные вещи, есть структура по разделам, а есть структура по блокам элементов (под препроцессоров). Реально сделать одновременно 2 структуры, когда макет проекта полностью нарисован и готов, но что делать, когда изначально есть главная страница и 2 раздела? А потом каждые 2 недели добавляются новые разделы и форма в одном разделе может кардинально различаться с формой в другом разделе.

Comment: @Елена Левина, а по поводу переубеждения дизайнера это уже совсем другая история, опытного хорошего дизайнера зачастую не может убедить никто, поэтому он и опытный хороший дизайнер, потому что он делает дизайн, который может отстоять :) Вообщем, мы уже далеко отошли от темы, поэтому предлагаю закончить споры

Comment: @MasterAlex а вы погуглите на тему LESS (SASS) project organization. Почитайте на тему модульной верстки, и все станет на свои места. Вот если кратенько... папка less (sass и вообще что угодно) содержит: vendor (вендорные стили - фрэймворки, слайдеры и т.п.),  components (компоненты сайта, вроде кнопок, таблиц, типографики, лэйаутов и т.п.), helpers (переменные, миксины, функции), modules (модули сайта. Именно тут пишется большая часть стилей), pages (стили конкретно для каждой страницы. Используется, когда нужно кастомизировать модуль или компонент для какой-то конкретной страницы).

Comment: .. в коммент не вместилось.. Все вот эти штучки в основном файле стили должны подключаться в вышеизложенном порядке - vendor, helpers (вот их можно на самом деле поменять местами), дальше components, modules, pages. Все. Никаких сложностей не возникнет и не важно, есть у вас там макеты или нет. Ну и вообще, начиная проект, дизайнер сам должен не рисовать абы как, а пользоваться своими же нарисованными вещами. Потому что знаю я, что любят - там кнопка Save зеленая, а вдругом месте - синяя (такой, простой вариант проблемы). Решается простым конфирмом чего-либо одного.

Comment: @MasterAlex, все ваши затруднения достаточно несложно решаются. Вы совершенно правы, здесь уже вышли за рамки обсуждаемого вопроса. Пишите, например в скайп (nasty.dyke), помогу.

Comment: Кстати, те же градиенты, как правило, одни и те же через весь сайт. Сделать несколько миксинов на каждый вид градиента, и подмешивать их к нужным элементам - настолько упрощает вёрстку. :)